# How to display only the first line when an exception is raised?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a try block in one of my methods. When an exception is raised, I have it display on a label, but every time one is raised, it adds multiple lines of code when I only want to get the first line of the exception without the "at System.String.CompareTo(Object value) at Example.Main()". How do I only get the first line?

Comment: You can parse it out of the callstack yourself: `var message = ex.ToString(); var firstLine = message.Substring(0, message.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));`

Comment: Can you share with us the code where you are populating the label in the catch block. This would help to better to understand the issue(s) you are facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Unless you needed more info on your exception, you can choose from the following properties:

```
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Source.ToString());
 Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
 Console.WriteLine(ex.TargetSite.ToString());
```